# No orderby in LINQ query, but ORDER BY in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, sql-execution-plan

I have a LinqToEntities query that does not use an orderby clause, but on the resulting SQL query, there is an ORDER BY clause (which costs 77% on the query on execution plan).

**Does anyone know why the ORDER BY clause is added and how can I remove it (if possible) ?**

Here is the LinqToEntities query :

```
var classementsQuery =
    from classement in _dbContext.Classements
                                 .Include(c => c.Operations)
                                 .Include("Operations.Matrices")
                                 .Include("Operations.Qualifications")
                                 .Include("Operations.Qualifications.Matrices")
                                 .Include("Operations.Qualifications.QualificationEtapes")
                                 .Include("Operations.Qualifications.QualificationEtapes.Matrices")
    where classement.Operations.Any()
    select classement;
```

Nota : each of the included entities relations are n-n.

Comment: What is the final SQL query that is generated from your LINQ?

Comment: you do have an order by in that query "orderby classement.ClassementId"

Comment: You're right, @HonorableChow, this was a temp test that ended in my clipboard... I removed it in the OP. There (still) is an order by in the SQL even if if there are no orderby in LINQ.

Comment: @Carl the ORDER BY is : `ORDER BY [Project13].[ClassementId] ASC, [Project13].[C94] ASC, [Project13].[C3] ASC, [Project13].[C1] ASC, [Project13].[C35] ASC, [Project13].[C39] ASC, [Project13].[C65] ASC, [Project13].[C69] ASC`. The whole SQL query is a 600 line SQL query... Do you really want to see it ? Can I ask you why ?

Comment: @DudePascalou, lol, not if it's 600 lines long! I wanted to see if there was a visible reason that EF was doing this. I am not 100% sure, but I think that EF adds an orderby clause when you use an include function, so that it groups associated records for efficiency when mapping the results back to objects on the other side, and I don't think it's removable without breaking your query down to not use includes.

Comment: @Carl Thanks for the track. If you're right, it would be a big drawback because in my case, the `ORDER BY` costs 77% on the execution plan! Or I use EF the wrong way... Which may not be false...